# Android PayPal SDK and Fragments

Tags: android, paypal, android-fragments

I used PayPal SDK before in my regular apps. Here are the steps I take in a normal activity

**a)** on activity's onCreate I make a new thread to init the PayPal library

**b)** if the init goes well, I create a PayPal button and add it in one of my layouts

**c)** on PayPal button's onClick I start a new activity for result where the user makes the payment

**d)** on activity's onActivityResult I check if payment was successfully and save the info

This worked well so far but things get messy when I try to use the same approach on a fragment. My fragment has a layout with 2 EditTexts and a LinearLayout that will host the Paypal button

So far I did it like this:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

        libraryInitializationThread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    initLibrary();
                    // The library is initialized so let's create our CheckoutButton and update the UI.
                    if (PayPal.getInstance().isLibraryInitialized()) {
                        hRefresh.sendEmptyMessage(INITIALIZE_SUCCESS);
                    } else {
                        hRefresh.sendEmptyMessage(INITIALIZE_FAILURE);
                    }
                }
            };
            libraryInitializationThread.start();
}

private void initLibrary() {
        PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();

        if (pp == null) {
            pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(context, getString(R.string.paypal_sandbox_id), PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);
            pp.setLanguage("en_US"); // Sets the language for the library.
            pp.setDynamicAmountCalculationEnabled(false);
        }
    }
```

So far, on `pp = PayPal.initWithAppID` I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment FragmentPayPal{415f43f8} not attached to Activity
```

Now my questions are:

- where and how should I init the paypal library ?
- from my fragment, can I start an activity for result and catch onActivityResult ?

Thank you.

Comment: yes you can catch OnActivityResult in fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the approach I used in the end was, simply, init paypal library before adding the fragment, in my main hosting activity. In this way it works just fine.